# Botão com escritas em cima da outra

Tags: css, html5

Tenho esse botão, gostaria de adicionar duas palavras nele, mas exibindo uma em cima da outra, já tentei usar um `<br>` entre elas mas é como se criasse outro botão, eu gostaria de um botão com as proporções que estão ali, mas que um texto ficasse em cima e o outro embaixo, eu não manjo muito de css, alguém saberia como fazer? Gostaria de deixar Finalizar em cima e Compra embaixo

```
<button type="button" title="Finalizar Pedido" class="button btn-checkout btn-inline " 
        style="width: 93px; line-height: 50px; display: inline-block;"><span><span>Finalizar Compra</span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso o problema é que você colocou o `line-height` como *50px*, então quando você criava uma quebra de linha, as duas linhas ficavam com *50px* de tamanho, resultando assim um elemento com *100px* de altura (*50px* para cada linha).

Para resolver isso, basta trabalhar com o `padding` ao invés do `line-height`. Com o `padding` você controla o espaçamento entre as bordas e o conteúdo do elemento.

Segue abaixo seu exemplo alterado:

```html
<button type="button" title="Finalizar Pedido" class="button btn-checkout btn-inline " 
        style="width: 93px; display: inline-block; padding: 10px 0 10px 0;"><span><span>Finalizar Compra</span></span></button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, foi isso então, pq eu normalmente uso o line-height.

Comment: Eu copiei e colei com as mesma propriedades do seu, mas aqui o texto estoura do button e sai da area..

Comment: Neste caso é provavelmente porque você está usando uma largura fixa com um texto muito grande. Sugiro você colocar o <br> para a quebra de linha, retirar a largura fixa e colocar um padding também nas laterais, assim o botão fica dinâmico se ajustando ao conteúdo.